# Searching and inserting data if not exist using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert data using a stored procedure while searching based on `Customer` and `AccountNumber`. Is there any way I can write following code in shorter form? Should I create a stored procedure in database for this or just use this to insert from VB directly?

```
declare @Customer int ,@AccountNumber int

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_A 
               WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_A 
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_B
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer 
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_A 
               WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_A 
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_C
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer 
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table_A 
               WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table_A 
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_D
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer 
END
```

Comment: Instead of using `IF` statements, add the condition to the `WHERE` clause. **Should** you create an SP - totally up to you.

Comment: Its recommended to list the columns for an `insert` statement, clearer and less likely to cause issues later on.

Comment: I am checking if the record does not exist in table A then only insert from table B or C or D. Do you mean to add `where` condition for tables? I will add the list of columns.

Comment: No, for example your first insert, you can add to the `where` clause `and not exists (SELECT * FROM Table_A where AccountNumber = @AccountNumber and Customer = @Customer)` i.e. do everything set based instead of procedural.

Comment: Also: using the `TOP 1` *without* an `ORDER BY` is pretty useless - you're getting 1 arbitrary column since you haven't defined what you want your rows to be ordered by .....

Comment: How about using UNION ALL for Table_B, Table_C and Table_D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining all the comments here is some shorter code. Points to note:

1. Its recommended to always fully list the columns involved in an `INSERT` statement. Its clearer what is happening, and not going to cause issues if you have `IDENTITY` columns, or change your table definition in future.
2. `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` is going to return random results which is not usually what you want.

```
    INSERT INTO Table_A 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_B
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_C
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM Table_D
        WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber AND Customer = @Customer
    ) X
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table_A A
        WHERE A.AccountNumber = X.AccountNumber AND A.Customer = X.Customer
    )
```